# Tooltip Not Showing in correct place

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using MatTooltipModule in my application as such

```
<div class="input-group" matTooltipPosition="right"
     matTooltip= "If you have multiple valve sizes this cost of ownership form needs to be completed for each size.">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]="cons.valveNumber" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
</div>
```

but when I run the code, the tooltip is on the left instead of the right.
Why is it showing up on the left?

**Edit:** If the tooltip does not fit on the right side, does the matTooltipModule automatcially move it to the left? If it does, how can you leave it on the right?

Answer (score 5):

It's because you should use `[matTooltipPosition]="'right'"`, don't forget brackets and pass a string (I guess that you mean `right` as a string in your case, not a variable which keeps a string).

Here is a full list of tooltip positions:

```
"before"
"after"
"above"
"below"
"left"
"right"
```

I also suggest to take a look at `"after"` position, may be it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I've found that NOT using brackets (matTooltipPosition="right" instead of [matTooltipPosition]="'right'") works fine as here passing a string (rather than an expression) is the desired behavior. It also looks cleaner to me. It's possible that this has been fixed in a more recent version of Angular material.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your html
placement="left"